# mysql - fetch related rows from multiple tables without all combinations

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, union

Let's say I have a primary table `record`, and it has 2 related tables `fields` and `comments`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE record (id int primary key, name varchar(20))
CREATE TABLE fields (record_id int, name varchar(20), val int)
CREATE TABLE comments (record_id int, who varchar(20), comment text)
```

I would like to run one query that fetches a set of records AND fetches all the related fields for that record, AND fetches all the comments related to that record.

If I do left joins to ensure I get the records, I would use:

```sql
select * from record
     left join fields on (fields.record_id = record.id)
     left join comments on (comments.record_id = record.id)
     order by record.id
```

The problem is, I get back n * m rows for each record, where n is the number of fields, and m is the number of comments. I want to get back n + m rows (what makes sense is that the fields columns are all null while returning the comments, and the comments columns are all null while returning the fields). Is there a way to make this work aside from inserting a dummy comment and dummy field to join with? I would  very much prefer not to have to perform an extra query for each record.

I suppose this is not mysql specific, but that's what I'm using for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get back n * m rows for each record, where n is the number of fields, and m is the number of comments. I want to get back n + m rows

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM record
    LEFT JOIN fields ON (fields.record_id = record.id) /* maybe INNER JOIN ? */
    LEFT JOIN comments ON (1=0)
UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM record
    LEFT JOIN fields ON (1=0)
    LEFT JOIN comments ON (comments.record_id = record.id) /* maybe INNER JOIN ? */
-- ORDER BY record.id
```

Comment: I'll add that I wanted the data to be returned together, so I had to sort based on a common field in the data. Unfortunately, (on the real data) I had to use a column index to sort by which is kind of horrible.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get back n + m rows (what makes sense is that the fields columns are all null while returning the comments, and the comments columns are all null while returning the fields)

One option uses `union all` in a subquery, then a `left join`:

```
select *
from record r
left join (
    select record_id, name, val, null who, null comment from fields
    union all record_id, select null, null, who, comment from comments
) x on x.record_id = r.record_id
```

That's a weird resultset though.